# Crop a UIImage according to visible area in a UIImageView UIViewContentMode

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiimageview, uiimage

I am setting a `UIImage` inside a `UIImageView`. The `UIImageView` can have its content mode set to one of the available ones:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, UIViewContentMode) {
    UIViewContentModeScaleToFill,
    UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit,      // contents scaled to fit with fixed aspect. remainder is transparent
    UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill,     // contents scaled to fill with fixed aspect. some portion of content may be clipped.
    UIViewContentModeRedraw,              // redraw on bounds change (calls -setNeedsDisplay)
    UIViewContentModeCenter,              // contents remain same size. positioned adjusted.
    UIViewContentModeTop,
    UIViewContentModeBottom,
    UIViewContentModeLeft,
    UIViewContentModeRight,
    UIViewContentModeTopLeft,
    UIViewContentModeTopRight,
    UIViewContentModeBottomLeft,
    UIViewContentModeBottomRight,
};
```

**I would like to crop the image such that the proportions will match the content mode.** 

How is this achieved?

Answer (score 1):

I don't this you can use the content mode to achieve this. Please try with below core graphics code:

```
- (UIImage *)cropVisiblePortionOfImageView:(UIImageView *)imageView {

  CGFloat zoomScaleX=imageView.frame.size.width/initialWidth;
  CGFloat zoomScaleY=imageView.frame.size.height/initialHeight;
  CGSize zoomedSize=CGSizeMake(initialWidth*zoomScaleX,initialHeight*zoomScaleY);

  UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(zoomedSize);
  [imageView.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, zoomedSize.width, zoomedSize.height)];
  UIImage *zoomedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

  UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(initialWidth, initialHeight));
  [zoomedImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(imageView.frame.origin.x, imageView.frame.origin.y)];
  UIImage *cropedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

  return cropedImage;
}
```

Comment: This will return an image with the size of the view. I need the full resolution image. cropped with those proportions